# how to run npm install --save-dev within node.js

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I've created a cli to format my project and install some dependencies.

I try to run

```js
const runNpm = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    npm.load(function(err) {
      // handle errors

      npm.commands.install(
        ["@angular/core", "@angular/cli --save-dev"],
        function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          console.log("dependencies installed");
          resolve();
        }
      );

      npm.on("log", function(message) {
        console.log(message);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Without `--save-dev` it work perfectly
I've searched on internet, but couldn't find nothing.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what's the use case for running npm commands withing node.js rather than doing this via package.json?

Comment: @Qiniso I have a cli that format an angular project newly created (Create folder structure, generated base files and update tslint). 
Because I'm using [tslint-config-standard-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-config-standard-plus) I want my cli to being able to download the required dependencies without having to do anything.
It may exist another solution that I'm not aware of in that case, I would be glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the solution that will save the package into the dev list, you have to use `npm.load()` as follows:

```
var npm = require('npm');

npm.load({ 'save-dev': true }, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    npm.commands.install(['@angular/core', '@angular/cli'], function (err, data) {
        if (err) return console.error(err)
    });
});
```

Original answer is here: [Programmatically install a npm package, providing --save-dev flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701183/programmatically-install-a-npm-package-providing-save-dev-flag)

Comment: Thx a lot, I see, then this question is a duplicate of the link you shared. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You can check the solution here: [Can I install a NPM package from javascript running in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957529/can-i-install-a-npm-package-from-javascript-running-in-node-js) for general npm packages installation using npm package manager from javascript code.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the link.   
If I understand it right, it isn't possible to do it directly via `npm.commands.[something]` but rather to do it like that.  

```shell
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
child = exec('npm install ffi').stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```?  _thx to [the Vyacheslav answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19406194/11135174)_

Comment: @rbalet I believe you can use the both methods and you will reach the same result.

Comment: do you have a sample for the first method? It's what I'm not able to find..